# Where does a downloaded PDF go when running tests in an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

In my selenium tests, I'm downloading a PDF from a chart in my application, and then counting the files in the directory to ensure its incremented by 1, to prove the file was successfully downloading. This of course works fine when running locally, but when running this in my Azure DevOps pipeline, although the line that presses the button works fine, I don't know what the default download file path is to compare the before and after number. (Like c:\downloads) for example.

I understand DevOps sets temp folders for pipeline runs (Like d:\a\1) for example, but I'm not sure where downloads go. Does this even happen? Will I be able to keep this specific piece of functionality in my tests?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a variable named `system.debug` and set the value to `true`. Then trigger the pipeline, check the debug log to see whether the PDF is downloaded and what's the download path.
2. Add a `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` task at the end of your pipeline. Check the PDF in the artifact.

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Comment: I used this method, but unfortunately it didn't aid me in my quest. Through another post and trial and error, I found the answer to my question. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Thanks for your update. Would you please share the answer to your question? So that it can help others who have the same question as you.

Comment: For sure - will add now!

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\VssAdministrator\Downloads   is the correct path for anyone else who might need to know this!